# CloudFront HTTP/3 Enabled but doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, http3

I have two AWS CloudFront distributions, one over an S3 bucket and one over an Application Load Balancer (ALB).  On both of them I checked the box "Enabled HTTP/3".  While using my application I noticed all my requests were running over http/2 so I checked my website with

```
curl --https3 https://my.website.com
```

and using https://domsignal.com/http3-test and got back that my site is not HTTP/3 compatible. The instructions from aws, [CloudFront New HTTP/3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-http-3-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/), only say to check the box.

What else could I be doing wrong? I thought the one in front of an ALB might not be able to because the ALB only supports HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 but I would still expect my distribution in front of S3 to run over HTTP/3.

I'm not sure how else to test either, but any question, help, or problem solving tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Not aware of a `Enable HTTP/3 Box`. When I create a distribution, I can see the Supported HTTP versions section which lets you select HTTP/2 and/or HTTP/3. That was working.